# Python or Java module to render HTML page on server side and obtain DOM object

Tags: java, python, webkit, rendering, server-side

I am looking for a library in Python OR Java that can use webkit or similar rendering engine on the server side (without GUI) and return the DOM object for further processing like selecting the elements etc.

Comment: The idea behind DOM processing is to provide client side interactivity. Doing it on the server side doesn't really make sense... Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to get Javascript processed on the server side to generate the final DOM that can be used for creating the snapshot of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process (execute) the javascript on headless server to generate the HTML snapshot, try using a tool like Selenium.

Selenium will allow you to fully render the HTML webpage on server side and then you can use the generated HTML to make a snapshot.